# "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" - debugging tornado nginx using vscode

Tags: nginx, visual-studio-code, tornado, remote-debugging, referrer-policy

My app (built as a collection of services) is using tornado with nginx.
I'm trying to debug it using vscode (remote debugging).
I stopped the original api service and ran the one in vscode instead.
When trying to send a request using chrome (macOS), I'm getting status code 500 "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"

Any idea?

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe the server code assumes there’s a Referer request header but when there’s no Referer request header, it throws some unhandled exception, which leads to an internal server failure and so causes the server to send a 500 response. And the reason there’s no Referer request header is, browsers don’t send it in some cases when the Referrer-Policy request header is set to strict-origin-when-cross-origin.

Comment: mmm... it's been a while since I solved it, I should have documented it here... 
if I recall correctly it was an environment variable related... 
thank you for the effort with the wild guess